# How do i resize image given by Hotelbeds api?

Tags: image

i'm using Hotelbeds api, it's get an image like

`http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/001499/001499a_hb_w_002.jpg`

and it's so small to show, i'm wondering if have a way to resize up or exist other url to give me a bigger image

Answer (score 2):

add the word **bigger** after  /giata/
[image]
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/bigger/00/001499/001499a_hb_w_002.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Use the following information from their documentation;

IMPORTANT NOTE:

The hotel images are not returned with the full path. Note you need to add the image path to the following base url for the different sized images: 
    http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/

```
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/ + {path} For 320 pixel-wide images (standard size)
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/ + {path} For 74 pixel-wide images (thumbnail size)
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/medium/ + {path} For 117 pixel-wide images
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/bigger/ + {path} For 800 pixel-wide images
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/xl/ + {path} For 1024 pixel-wide images
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/xxl/ + {path} For 2048 pixel-wide images
http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/original/ + {path} For images in its original size (please note that this is not a standard and actual size may vary between hotels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove /small/ from your link.